# downloading and installing a program using python

Tags: python, wget

I need to download and install Java JDK on various systems using python code. I used the Wget module however, I don't know the directory of the downloaded file, hence there is no result

```
import platform
import requests
import wget

url_windows='https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe'
url_mac='https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg'
url_linux='https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb'

if platform.system == 'Windows':
    wget.download(url_windows)
if platform.system == 'Linux':
    wget.download(url_linux)
if platform.system == 'Mac':
    wget.download(url_mac)
```

what can I do?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/wget/#data) `wget.download()` returns the filename, and it seems by default it will just download to the current directory, like most programs. As @CrazyElf pointed out you're just not running the function because you're not calling `sys.platform()`.

Comment: As an aside are you sure you want to use this `wget` module? It is a nice and easy interface, but, it doesn't seem to have been maintained since 2015.

Comment: I'm a beginner as you noticed, so can you please suggest something? maybe requests?

Answer (score 2):

platform.system is a function, you should call it to compare it's return value with string, so use platform.system() instead. For now you are not using wget anywhere in your code actually because all comparations failed.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it is downloaded in the current directory where you run it.

See `help(wget.download)`:

```
Help on function download in module wget:

download(url, out=None, bar=<function bar_adaptive at 0x100ddcdd0>)
    High level function, which downloads URL into tmp file in current
    directory and then renames it to filename autodetected from either URL
    or HTTP headers.

    :param bar: function to track download progress (visualize etc.)
    :param out: output filename or directory
    :return:    filename where URL is downloaded to
```

It returns the filename of the downloaded file, so you can use `os.path.abspath` to get the full path:

```
>>> import os
>>> import wget
>>> f = wget.download("https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg")
100% [................................................................................] 5307 / 5307>>> 
>>> f
'jdk-13.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg'
>>> os.path.abspath(f)
'/Users/gino/jdk-13.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg'
>>>
```

The function also accepts an `out` parameter so that you can explicitly set the download path.

---

As a side note, as mentioned by [@CrazyElf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478483/2745495), you should be using `platform.system()` to get the string names of the OS ("Windows", "Darwin", etc.) and not `platform.system` which is a function:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system
<function system at 0x100f19170>
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
```

(*Notice that it returns "Darwin" on a Mac and not "Mac".*)